# Cannot add click events to list items

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

This is my first foray into using Javascript with HTML. I'm trying to add click events to the list items in an ordered list, but something about the way I'm doing it isn't working. Can somebody shed some light on this for me?

I create a function in my `head` that should delegate all click events on the list items of a specified list to a given function, and in that given function I try to raise a simple alert with the text of the list item. Eventually I want to do more, but I'm just trying to get the simple click events to work first.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Attach an event handler to the 'topfriends' list to handle click events.
      function attachEventHandlerToList() {
          document.getElementById("#top4list").delegate("li", "click", function(clickEvent) {
              alert(this.innerHTML());
          });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="topfriends">
        <h3>Top 4 Most Friendable Friends</h3>
        <ol id="top4list" onload="attachEventHandlerToList()">
            <li>Brady</li>
            <li>Graham</li>
            <li>Josh</li>
            <li>Sean</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's do something like this

```
<ul id="parent-list">
    <li id="a">Item A</li>
    <li id="b">Item B</li>
    <li id="c">Item C</li>
    <li id="d">Item D</li>
    <li id="e">Item E</li>
    <li id="f">Item F</li>
</ul>
```

Now write the javascript for this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // locate your element and add the Click Event Listener
    document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        // e.target is our targetted element.
                    // try doing console.log(e.target.nodeName), it will result LI
        if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
            console.log(e.target.id + " was clicked");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Please refer to this write-up on Javascript Event Delegates
http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Also, below link is the fiddle that I created
http://jsfiddle.net/REtHT/

hope this helps !

Comment: Ahh, this works too! And I bet it's more efficient than assigning individual click events to each list item, which is what I was trying to avoid by using 'delegate()'.

Comment: But wait! How can I get at the text within the list item? Using `e.target.id` gets the id of the `li`, right? I will be generating this list eventually, and `e.target.innerHTML` doesn't print out anything.

Comment: Nevermind, `innerHTML` totally works. I guess I either misspelled it or didn't save the changes lol. My bad!

Comment: It's only more efficient when you bind the event handler, after that it's less efficient on every click to check the target everytime someone clicks the parent OL.

Answer (score 9):

`delegate()` is a deprecated jQuery method, and no such method exists in plain JS.
To attach an event handler in JS you'd use `addEventListener`, and for older versions of IE you'll need `attachEvent` as well, that's why it's a little tricky with cross browser event handlers.
`onclick`, `onmouseenter` etc. will work in all browsers, but it's consider a better practice to use `addEventListener` / `attachEvent`.

Also, you have to run the script after the elements are added to the DOM, otherwise they are not available. The usual way is to insert the script after the elements, or use a DOM ready event handler.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="topfriends">
  <h3>Top 4 Most Friendable Friends</h3>
  <ol id="top4list">
    <li>Brady</li>
    <li>Graham</li>
    <li>Josh</li>
    <li>Sean</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var lis = document.getElementById("top4list").getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener('click', doStuff, false);
    }

    function doStuff() {
        alert( this.innerHTML );
    }
</script>
</body>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sTh7g/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll give this a try. This is really my first time adding behavior to my HTML, so I don't know anything too detailed about event handling. Also, the project I was testing this for uses JQuery, so I thought the delegate() method would be fine, but I guess I need to require the library or something when I use it? I'm new to JS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work with child Node and Parent Node also.

```js
 var visitorList = document.getElementById("visitor");
        visitorList.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            var visitorId;
            if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
                visitorId = e.target.id;
                console.log(e.target.id);
            }
            if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "H1") {
                visitorId = e.srcElement.parentElement.id;
                console.log(e.srcElement.parentElement.id);
            }
            //console.log(visitorId);
        });
```

```html
<ul id="visitor">
        <li id="a" style="background: #CCCCCC; padding: 10px;"><h1 style="background: #437ba9;">Visitor A</h1></li>
        <li id="b"><h1>Visitor B</h1></li>
        <li id="c"><h1>Visitor C</h1></li>
        <li id="d"><h1>Visitor D</h1></li>
        <li id="e"><h1>Visitor E</h1></li>
        <li id="f"><h1>Visitor F</h1></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by using `querySelectorAll`

```
  <ul class="stuffList">
    <li>Stuff 1</li>
    <li>Stuff 2</li>
    <li>Stuff 3</li>
    <li>Stuff 4</li>
    <li>Stuff 5</li>
  </ul>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelectorAll('ul.stuffList li').forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            console.log(e.target)
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello why not doing it easier by replacing onLoad directy by onClick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function olClicked(){
alert(this.innerHTML());
}
</script>
<ol id="top4list" onClick="olClicked()">
```

Comment: i get a type error when I try this. 'this' is apparently the window, not the list item. The reason I was using delegate is because I need to specify different behavior for each list item.